# What are the best ways to remove ambiguities in spoken English?

Tags: english, ambiguity

I often find it hard to quickly switch between communication conventions in the colloquial speech, and those in a technical environment.

A lot of this comes from ambiguities of how English as a langue is used, and how loosely or tightly the meaning of the words I'm saying are meant to be translated.

Are there any tricks that I can employ commonly across both styles of speech for dealing with this?

<sub>related:
[What range of strategies are common in natural languages for providing unambiguous answers to negative yes-no questions?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6409/what-range-of-strategies-are-common-in-natural-languages-for-providing-unambiguo)</sub>

Comment: Spoken English is much less ambiguous than written English. Intonation, stress, rhythm, gaze direction, posture, facial expressions, and gestures all constrain the interpretation of words and sentences. What gets written down is much much less than what is spoken. So the answer to to your question is "Pay attention to the actual speech, not the words it uses."

Comment: @jlawler fair point: perhaps I'm concentrating on the wording too much and should focus more on eye contact.

Comment: Questions of this nature might attract more practical answers on the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Actually, I feel it would be just as proper to move it to http://english.stackexchange.com/ (which I couldn't seem to find before asking this question)